# Javascript- Smoothscroll vs Touch Link interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below is embedded into my html file but it seems to interfere with each other (first script is for touch links, second script is a smooth scroll function).

If I were to delete the first my smooth scroll would work fine. 
But with these two combined my smooth scroll is messed up.
I think the solution may be within -window.open(link,'_self')- this line.
My knowledge of Javascript is minimal so any help would be very appreciated!

Greetings from Belgium.

```
<script>
$(function () {    
    $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
        var link = $(this).attr('href');   
        window.open(link,'_self');

        return false; // prevent anchor click    
    });    
});

</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $( '#Slider1' ).sliderPro({
                width: 1000,
                height: 520,
                arrows: true,
                buttons: true,
                waitForLayers: true,
                thumbnailWidth: 200,
                thumbnailHeight: 100,
                thumbnailPointer: true,
                autoplay: false,
                autoScaleLayers: false,
                breakpoints: {
                    500: {
                        thumbnailWidth: 120,
                        thumbnailHeight: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine both scripts in this order, Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
            $( '#Slider1' ).sliderPro({
                width: 1000,
                height: 520,
                arrows: true,
                buttons: true,
                waitForLayers: true,
                thumbnailWidth: 200,
                thumbnailHeight: 100,
                thumbnailPointer: true,
                autoplay: false,
                autoScaleLayers: false,
                breakpoints: {
                    500: {
                        thumbnailWidth: 120,
                        thumbnailHeight: 50
                    }
                }
            });
 $('a').on('click touchend', function() { 
        var link = $(this).attr('href');   
        window.open(link,'_self');

        return false; // prevent anchor click    
    }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hey, `remove return false;`. try then

Comment: It doesn't work, I also need the return false; to not double touch buttons on ipad etc,..
PS: the first script is from my photo slider and not from the smooth scroll like I previously said.